# SPDY multiplexing makes requests slower than HTTP

Tags: android, performance, okhttp, spdy, multiplexing

I have an application that makes a mixture of network requests, some small items (~20kB) and some large items (>2mB). If my understanding of SPDY is correct, SPDY multiplexes requests on the same connection, so the smaller requests could potentially be slowed down if they're behind the larger requests. Since OkHttp doesn't support prioritization of requests yet, is there anything I can do to prevent this situation?

I tried using an OkHttp client for the small requests and another OkHttp client for the larger requests but this doesn't seem to solve the problem since the connections seem to be shared across clients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The multiplexing in SPDY interleaves requests and responses, so no call ever blocks on another call; they all just block on the available bandwidth.

That said, can create two `OkHttp` instances, each with its own connection pool.

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
okHttpClient.setConnectionPool(new ConnectionPool());
```